# Output simple text from HTML using Python/BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am building a Python function to input HTML email content and output simple text with very little formatting, but including line breaks for readability. The output is to be posted to a Slack channel.

Currently I am taking in the input text, unescaping (using `HTMLParser.HTMLParser.unescape` since this is in Python 2.7) and then cleaning using `BeautifulSoup.gettext()`. This outputs clean text, but since the output has been stripped of *all* formatting, the result is almost unreadable.

How can I force BeautifulSoup to include only newlines but strip all else?

My current code is as follows:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

def textify(raw_html):
  parser = HTMLParser()
  unescaped_html = parser.unescape(raw_html)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(unescaped_html)
  # get text
  text = soup.getText()
  return text
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of the html it's parsing? and what you expect the output to be?

Comment: Perhaps you can use something like [html2text](https://pypi.org/project/html2text/). html2text is a Python script that converts a page of HTML into clean, easy-to-read plain ASCII text. Better yet, that ASCII also happens to be valid Markdown (a text-to-HTML format).